# How to process the same image in parallel with Spark avoiding unecessary copies?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using PySpark to process image data. My images are stored in Amazon S3 and I have a data structure that associates each image with a list of polygons (might have up to 500 polygons, for example, and this is a source of data skew):

```
image_path_poly_list = [(ImagePath1, [poly1_1, poly1_2, ..., poly1_N]), ..., (ImagePathM, [polyM_1, polyM_2, ..., polyM_K])]
```

Each image may contain one or more channels (only Red or Red, Green, Blue, for example) and each channel might be up to 11000 x 11000 pixels. In other words, each channel might contain up to 500 mb of data. Therefore, an image could occupy more than 1.5 GB of space (considering 3 channels, the "common" case). The images are in .jp2 format (very compressed, actually) and decompression is quite slow and cpu-demanding.

I would like to clip every image with its respective polygons. Since, images are too large to fit in the Spark Driver, I'd better download/open the images in the Spark Slaves. So I create a RDD from `image_path_poly_list` and afterwards do a map operation to download/open the images.

```
rdd1 -> [(Image1, [poly1_1, poly1_2, ..., poly1_N]), ..., (ImageM, [polyM_1, polyM_2, ..., polyM_K])]
```

Next, I do a flatMap to get a new rdd of pairs:

```
rdd2 -> (Image1, poly1_1), (Image1, poly1_2), ..., (ImageM, polyM_K)
```

Then I do a map to to clip each pair of Image and Polygon. Below is the idea of my code:

```
def openImage(elem):
    imagePath, list_of_poly = elem 
    image = downloadAndOpen(imagePath) # download from S3 and load into memory  
    return image, list_of_poly 

def expand(elem):
    image, list_of_poly = elem
    return [(image, poly) for poly in list_of_poly]

def process(elem):
    image, poly = elem
    return clip(image, elem) # clip returns the clipped image

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(image_path_poly_list).map(openImage)
rdd2 = rdd1.flatmap(expand).map(process).collect()
```

However, I noticed that the cluster I use is almost idle with only a few cores being used after some time, like if the data is skewed. The only source of skew I can find in data is the variable number of polygons that each image can have. I thought that flatMap would rebalance the workload, since the processing time of a pair (Image, Poly) is almost pretty constant.

Then, after some web research, I think that all pairs (Image, poly) still lie in the same partition after flatMap and each partition (as far as I understand) is processed serially by one core. Therefore, I tried to do a repartition with a huge *numPartitions*. This, however, is very slow, since images get cached into disk:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.flatmap(expand).repartition(hugeNumPartitions).map(process).collect()
```

Is there a way of doing something like a parallel for, so that I can use the same image to be clipped in parallel with a list of polygons? I think that using multiprocessing pools inside a map could do the job, but I am trying to avoid this and looking for a solution using only Spark.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you provide images here (how do you store them, how they end up in the RDD, how do you attach ops)?